# Dummy indicator for cross country ID repetitions

Tags: r, tibco, indicator

Here is my problem: I have a table with isin and countries, like this:

```
ISIN          COUNTRY

XX0001        ITALY         
XX0002        FRANCE        
XX0003        ITALY         
XX0001        FRANCE        
XX0002        ITALY         
XX0004        FRANCE
```

I would like to create a new column with an indicator taking value 1 if the same name appears in both countries, 0 otherwise.

```
ISIN          COUNTRY       INDICATOR 

XX0001        ITALY         1
XX0002        FRANCE        1
XX0003        ITALY         0
XX0001        FRANCE        1
XX0002        ITALY         1
XX0004        FRANCE        0
```

I am working in Tibco Spotfire that works also with native R language.

Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ISIN = c("XX0001", "XX0002", "XX0003", "XX0001", "XX0002", "XX0004"),
                      COUNTRY = c("ITALY", "FRANCE", "ITALY", "FRANCE", "ITALY", "FRANCE")),
                 .Names = c("ISIN", "COUNTRY"), class = "data.frame",
                 row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `duplicated`

```
df1$INDICATOR <- as.integer(duplicated(df1$ISIN)|!duplicated(df1$COUNTRY))
df1$INDICATOR
#[1] 1 1 0 1 1 0
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, INDICATOR := +(uniqueN(COUNTRY)>1) , ISIN]
```